# Generating a format string from a user defined class?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any relatively simple way with template metaprogramming or similar to take a struct like:

```
struct data { 
     int32_t off;
     int16_t len;
     int8_t  bla;
};
```

and generate a format string from it?

Something like `format<data>() == "OFF/SL LEN/SI BLA/SB"`

That's not the actual format I need, but something of a simple textual nature would be good.

Comment: No.   Reflection is coming "soon".  There were talks on it last year and this year at cppcon.  You can play with "metaclasses" (a superset of reflection - see the parts that say `for...`) here: https://cppx.godbolt.org/z/r8eCL9 but this is all fantasy world stuff for now.  That said if you build your struct with macros or something like boost hana then maybe you can do something like this - but not with a traditional struct definition like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's anything simple you can do without using third party libraries.  One approach that works (but requires some effort) is to define a `to_tuple` function for each type you'd like to convert.  For example:

```
auto to_tuple(data const& d)
{
    return std::tie(d.off, d.len, d.bla);
}
```

Your `format` function can then call `to_tuple` on the provided argument and use that to reflect on the types:

```
template <class... T> std::string format_impl(std::tuple<T...> const& obj)
{
   // do something with the tuple members
}

template <class T> std::string format(T const& obj)
{
    return format_impl(to_tuple(obj));
}
```

The "do something" bit is tricky if you're truly constrained to C++11.  In C++14 it's relatively easy with `std::index_sequence`.  In C++17, you can use a fold expression.